# How to contribute a runner implemetaion

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a JUnit test runner implementation that performs contract tests.  I would like to contribute the code base to junit.org.  Can anyone tell me how to make such a contribution?

The implementation is used by several projects and is mature enough that I have seen no new defects for some time.  Code base includes the runner and a maven plugin to report on the state of the code base under test.

Contract tests as defined here are tests against java interfaces where the same test should be run against all implementation of the interface.

I gave several talks about this package including one at FOSDEM, this implementation was also written up in Dr. Dobbs Journal.